# R: Can't find column when using case_when and mutate in tidyverse pipeline?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to use `mutate` and `case_when` in the `tidyverse` pipeline to create a new column that is calculated based on the conditions of another column. Here is my dataframe:

```
> bac_totalOTU
# A tibble: 1,470 × 6
# Groups:   OTU_ID, Phylum, Family, Genus [735]
   OTU_ID  Phylum                      Family              Genus              Treatment TOTAL_OTU
   <chr>   <fct>                       <fct>               <fct>              <fct>         <int>
 1 OTU10   Actinobacteria              Cellulomonadaceae   Cellulomonas       DOC Remo…       735
 2 OTU10   Actinobacteria              Cellulomonadaceae   Cellulomonas       None            458
 3 OTU100  Firmicutes                  Bacillaceae 1       Bacillus           DOC Remo…        42
 4 OTU100  Firmicutes                  Bacillaceae 1       Bacillus           None             61
 5 OTU1001 Planctomycetes              Gemmataceae         Gemmata            DOC Remo…         0
 6 OTU1001 Planctomycetes              Gemmataceae         Gemmata            None              0
 7 OTU1002 Candidatus Saccharibacteria Saccharibacteria_g… Saccharibacteria_… DOC Remo…         0
 8 OTU1002 Candidatus Saccharibacteria Saccharibacteria_g… Saccharibacteria_… None              0
 9 OTU1003 Chloroflexi                 Sphaerobacteraceae  Nitrolancea        DOC Remo…         0
10 OTU1003 Chloroflexi                 Sphaerobacteraceae  Nitrolancea        None              0
# … with 1,460 more rows
```

This data currently makes this plot, but I would like each bar normalized to 100%.
[Image of not normalized bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnSF4.png)

I'm trying to convert the `TOTAL_OTU` column into a percentage that is stored in a new column called `OTUpercent`. If the type of `Treatment` is "DOC Removed," then I want to divide by the total of the "DOC Removed" column. If not, I want to divide by the sum of the "None" column. Here is my code so far for that:

```
bac_totalOTU %>%
  select(OTU_ID, Phylum, Family, Genus, Treatment, TOTAL_OTU) %>%
  mutate(
    OTUpercent = case_when(
      Treatment == "DOC Removed" ~ TOTAL_OTU/bac_OTUsums[1,2],
      TRUE ~ TOTAL_OTU/bac_OTUsums[2,2]
    )
  )
```

I independently calculated the totals per `Treatment` and they are stored in the dataframe `bac_OTUsums` that is being called above:

```
> bac_OTUsums
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Treatment   totalByTreatment
  <fct>                  <int>
1 DOC Removed            27544
2 None                   25937
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `OTUpercent`.
ℹ `OTUpercent = case_when(...)`.
x undefined columns selected
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: OTU_ID = "OTU10", Phylum = Actinobacteria, Family = Cellulomonadaceae, Genus = Cellulomonas.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I did see in a previous post that someone had a similar issue, but it was due to the version of `dplyr` that they were using, but this was fixed in version 0.7.0. I'm using `dplyr_1.0.7`.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using `ggplot`, you can set `position = "fill"` in `geom_bar()` and it will normalize the bars to 100% without any data transformation.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. On my machine your code works. Try: `dplyr::select` and/or  `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: As for your error, my first guess is that it is because `bac_OTUsums` is a tibble, so `bac_OTUsums[row, column]` is also a tibble, not a single value. You might try changing to `bac_OTUsums[row, column, drop = TRUE]` or  `bac_OTUsums[[column]][row]` to get a value, not a 1x1 tibble.